# Can you Use jQuery's Drag n' Drop Inside a WYSIWYG Editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

Is there a way to get jQuery's drag and drop functionality to work inside the CKEditor?

I have a bunch of images on the left, and a generic template on the right, with placeholder images showing where you can put a picture. The user should be able to drag and drop an image into one of the template's placeholder images. The script will then resize the image to the same width as the dummy image and replace it. However this doesn't work when the code is inside of a textarea. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a workaround to get JavaScript/html to behave inside a textarea. Your best bet would probably be to replace your textareas with contenteditable divs.